# Why putting a background job into a script can make the job survive termination of the script and the caller of the script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process

In an interactive bash shell running inside lxterminal, if I run a background job

```
$ evince &
```

and then close the shell, the background job will be killed.

If I put the background command in a script, and run the script in an interactive bash shell:

```
$ cat test.sh 
!# /bin/bash

evince &
$ ./test.sh
$
```

after the script terminates, the background job still runs. Even after I terminates the interactive bash shell, the background job still continues running.

I wonder why putting a background job into a script and running the script can make the job survive both the termination of the script and the termination of the caller of the script? Is wrapping a job into a script a good way to make the job survive the termination of the script and the termination of the shell which invokes the script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. By "close the shell", I assume you mean closing the `lxterminal`
   window. The `lxterminal` and the interactive `bash` are connected to
   each other over a pseudo-TTY device, which is a kernel-level
   construct.

   If you do that while its interactive `bash` child process is still
   running, the `lxterminal` process will close its side of the
   pseudo-TTY. That causes the kernel to send a SIGHUP signal to the
   interactive `bash`.

   The **SIGNALS** chapter of `man bash` says:

   > The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting,
   >   an  interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or
   >   stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive
   >   the SIGHUP.
   >
   > To prevent the shell from sending the signal to a particular job, 
   >   it should be removed from the jobs table with the `disown` builtin
   >   (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to not receive SIGHUP using `disown -h`.

   The intended meaning of the SIGHUP signal is "the connection to the
   user's terminal was lost; save any unsaved work if necessary, and
   then exit in an orderly fashion." (For daemon processes, this is not
   applicable, so for them the signal is often used to mean "reread
   your configuration files" and/or "close and reopen your log files
   for log rotation".)

   As the man page says, the interactive `bash` will then resend the
   SIGHUP signal to all its children (unless told otherwise using
   `disown`). This is what causes your backgrounded `evince` to exit.
2. But **when you use a script**, your interactive shell `fork()`s a
   new process to run a shell to run the script, and then the new shell
   running the script `fork()`s yet again to run `evince`. After that,
   the script ends, so the shell running the script exits.

   At this point, the `evince` process will no longer have a parent
   process. But when you look at a `ps -ef` listing, there is never a
   process with an empty PPID field: *it is impossible for the process
   not to have a parent*. So, to deal with this situation, the kernel
   assigns the orphaned `evince` process PPID to 1, making it the
   adopted child of the `init` process. Now the original interactive
   `bash` does not know that the instance of `bash` that ran the script
   did start another process: this knowledge died along with the shell
   instance that ran the script.

   As a result, the interactive `bash` simply has no clue that there is
   an `evince` process that might need to have SIGHUP sent to it when
   the session ends.

   What you've achieved with that script is actually the bare-bones
   version of a technique used when intentionally *daemonizing*
   processes, known as a *double fork*. (Daemonizing a process = making
   it completely independent of the process and session that started
   it.)

   As you've seen, in practice, this is enough for making the `evince`
   process separate from the interactive `bash` but still keeping it a
   part of your GUI login session. But if you want a complete
   daemonization, there's a few other steps you should do before the
   second fork:

   - make sure that standard input, standard output and standard error are redirected to `/dev/null`
   - if any other file descriptors are open, close them
   - `cd /` so that your process won't accidentally interfere with the sysadmin mounting/unmounting filesystems, unless the process
     actually needs to access files in a particular filesystem
   - set `umask` explicitly to the value you want/need it to be
   - if `setsid` command is available, you should use it to disconnect the resulting process from your session's process group and make it
     fully separate (i.e. instead of `evince &` at the end of your
     script, you might use `exec setsid evince`).

   See here for a more detailed description of daemonizing in bash
   shell: http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-145.html

Comment: Thanks. I took the liberty to edit your post to make it look even more clear to me. Feel free to let me know if I was wrong.

Comment: In the first case `$ evince &`, the background job is running in a subshell of the invoking interactive shell. The background job is killed, when the invoking shell terminates, because the subshell is also interactive?

Answer (score 2):

The killing of the bacground evince it probably something in your logout profile.

using a script works because the shell that was running the the background task has already finished, you can get the same effect by typing.

```
( evince & )
```

That starts a subshell, the subshell backgrounds evince and then exits.
evince is now a daemon.